# How do you make a change to every line of code in python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I want to put quotation marks and a comma after ever line

```
apple
pear
squid
```

turns into:

```
      "apple",
      "pear",
      "squid",
```

But this if there were infinetly many.

Comment: get them into a list. iterate and make the changes. have you tried any python code so far?

Comment: Are you sure you mean to do this in _Python_, or is that a question about your editor?

Comment: This is likely better done with your text editor or command line.  UNIX (Linux, MacOSX, ...) can do this with the `sed` command.

Comment: What are `apple` `pear` and `squid`? variables? strings? You need a little more detail in your question relating to the context of your problem and what your desired result is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to print these strings in a different format, you can do:

```
strings = ['apple','pear','squid']

for item in strings:
  print '"{}",'.format(item)
```

This results in

```
"apple",
"pear",
"squid",
```